# How to set ndo_start_xmit cpu affinity in ethernet driver?

Tags: linux, linux-device-driver

On the receiving side we have the opportunity to choose the CPU that will process the receive queue (RPS). On the sender side XPS selects the send queue for the given CPU, but there is no way to select the CPU on which `ndo_start_xmit()` will be launched. Taskset is able to bind user task, but in `ndo_start_xmit()` binding differs.

In my case CPU0 reserved for polling kthread, because our NIC have no interrupts, therefore it is necessary. I want nothing else to run on this CPU.

Setting CPU1 for RPS on both nodes:

```
echo 0x2 > /sys/class/net/<dev>/queues/rx-0/rps_cpus
```

Then run iperf on two nodes:

```
host1: taskset -c 1 iperf -s
host2: taskset -c 1 iperf -c host1
```

After adding `pr_info("cpu%d\n", smp_processor_id());` in my `ndo_start_xmit()` method, see in dmesg:

```
host1: dmesg | grep cpu0 | wc -l
0
host2: dmesg | grep cpu0 | wc -l
6512
```

Is it possible to choose the CPU on which `ndo_start_xmit()` will be launched on the sender side?

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer to my question. Doubt that anyone will ever need it, but nevertheless. The kernel network stack initializes the next ndo_start_xmit() on the cpu where the dev_kfree_skb() function was called. In my case, i moved out dev_kfree_skb() from the polling kthread to a function that makes enqueuing.